# matplotlib embedded in tkinter won't exit mainloop uppon window closing

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I boiled my code down into this minimal reproducible example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
   
Dates=["a","b","c","d"]
Numbers=[1,4,2,6]


def test():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,7))
    ax.plot(Dates, Numbers, linestyle='-', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    def f_test():
        print("HI")
    f_test()
    root.mainloop()
    
test()
```

The problem im having is that whenever I call the function, it starts running but never ends. It keeps running even though I close the Tk window. I have laso tried with `'winfo_exists()'` But it just wont work.

I have `'f_test'` inside `'test()'` because irl I have 2 functions that are only used inside `'test()'` so i've defined them inside it.

Comment: Please create a minimal executable example that contains only relevant code for your problem (e.g. a `tkinter` GUI that changes the title of a `matplotlib` window at the push of a button) and translate comments function names to English so that everyone here can understand them. Maybe this exercise will already let you recognise the error in your code. My guess is that the `mainloop` call in the `conexion_Db_grafica` function is blocking further execution because it is a blocking loop.

Comment: yeah the problem is mainloop. Ty for advise ill probably take down this post and re do it later with a more precise example. Can you explain anyways what you mean in that last sentence?

Comment: The `mainloop` is an eventhandler. That means its basically an endless loop updating your GUI. So once you enter it. everything following in your code will never be reached. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) for reference. But this is only a quick assumption. Edit the post here like asked earlier and I will be happy to take a closer look and do my best to help you.

Comment: Done. i've posted a simplified version of my original problem fully in english. Btw thank you for your time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected in the comments this is due to the blocking tkinter `mainloop` which is never properly exited in your case.

> The mainloop is an eventhandler. That means its basically an endless loop updating your GUI. So once you enter it. Everything following in your code will never be reached. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158220/tkinter-understanding-mainloop) for reference.

Following this [tutorial from matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html) I implemented a closing routine `_on_closing` to stop the blocking `mainloop` and to destroy the `Tk` instance properly. This routine is triggert by the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` event when closing the tkinter window.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tkinter import Tk, Frame
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

Dates = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
Numbers = [1, 4, 2, 6]


def test():
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
    ax.plot(Dates, Numbers, linestyle='-', color='gray', alpha=0.5)
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frame)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill='both', expand=True)

    def f_test():
        print("HI")

    def _on_closing():
        root.quit()  # stops mainloop
        root.destroy()  # this is necessary on Windows to prevent Fatal Python Error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate

    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _on_closing)  # bind closing routine
    f_test()
    root.mainloop()


test()
```

Please note also that while the tkinter window is open `mainloop` is running and therefore the rest of your code is blocked until you close the window!

Comment: Oh i get it. Thank you very much! For all the previus advise, the explanation and for your patience :D

Comment: You're very welcome, it was a pleasure!